# using same session in multiple uiwebviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, session, uiwebview

I search the web a whole time and don't find any answers.
Is it possible that two or more UIWebViews share the same session? And how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They should share the same sessions by default, each app has it's own cookie jar, etc. You won't be able to share with Mobile Safari though.

Comment: so is it like cookies are maintained application wide and if a user logs in some site, next time session will be reestablished?